# Android Label/Icon - in AndroidManifest/Build options vs MainActivity

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In a Xamarin project, I can set the Android Label and Icon directly via the Build Options UI - which I believe updates the AndroidManifest.xml file

[image]

And I can also set it in code like so above the MainActivity class:

```
 [Activity(Label = "MyXamApp", Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher", Theme = "@style/MyXamApp.Splash",
        MainLauncher = true,
```

Does one take precedence over the other, do I need both, which is the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the icon in Option, it will then be used to automatically generate the manifest for you. This is the default value for the Android project.

When you set the Icon, Label in Activity, it would reset the Icon, Label at runtime.

Normally, we would set our own Icon, Label in Activity. If you do not set it again, it would use the Icon, Label value in AndroidManifest file.

Comment: this is a little confusing, are you saying that what's in MainActivity supersedes what's in the Build Options UI? Or are you saying if I set the Label and Icon in the Build options, that I don't need it again in the MainAcitivty?

Comment: yes, use one of them is enough. If you use both, the default value(Icon, Label in AndroidManifest) would be covered in Activity.

Comment: Is the AndroidManifest pulling directly from the Build options? or is that set manually?

Comment: When you set in Option, it would generate into the AndroidManifest file automatically. Most of the users should never need to manually modify AndroidManifest.xml.